# onChange() method in ContentObserver is calling late Android contacts

Tags: android, contentobserver

I am working for contacts changing in my application. I am using following service for the purpose. If I am adding any contact in my contact list then my onChange() method in ContentObserver is caching that change very late like after 50 seconds. I am registering my service in the start of my application.

My code is given below:

```
public class ContactService extends Service {

    private final ContentObserver contactsObserver = new ContentObserver(null) {

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
//          showNotification();
            Utils.executeAsyncTask(new UploadContactsAsync(ContactService.this), null);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // remove when done testing
//      android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        getApplication().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, contactsObserver);

        if(Prefs.create(getBaseContext()).getSync()) {
            Log.e("updating contacts", "updating contacts");
            new UploadContactsAsync(ContactService.this).execute();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(contactsObserver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

My main Activity from where i am registering my service

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.newsample_login);

        startService(new Intent(this, ContactService.class));
}
```

My Manifest file

```
<service android:name="com.ziza.services.ContactService" />
```

Comment: were you able to solve this?